# Подсчет количества элементов стека

Tags: c++, c, стек

Функция простая, но при переходе с последнего элемента на NULL происходит ошибка чтения данных. Не подскажете, в чем проблема?

```
int count(DynProduct* Beg)
{
    int count = 0;
    DynProduct* current = Beg;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->Next;
    }
    return(count);
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: Ошибка может быть, например, если вы у последнего элемента забыли поле Next сделать равным NULL. Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, нужно было последнему элементу поставить указатель NULL